# I can't run the first example in Qt

Tags: qt

I have just installed the qt 5.7.0 and mingw 5.30 32bit on windows 10 64bit pc.
When Qtcreator run the first example which is given by the Qt creator, I always got an error that is ;

> Starting C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.7\canvas3d\threejs\build-cellphone-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\cellphone.exe...
>   The program has unexpectedly finished.
>   C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.7\canvas3d\threejs\build-cellphone-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\cellphone.exe crashed.

There wasn't any error during compiling period
[image]

All settings are coming default and I didn't change anyting. 
MinGW settings seem normal on the compilers setting.

[image]

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Try to run the executable outside of QtCreator. Maybe it cannot find some dlls.

Comment: @AMA I doubt it comes from missing DLL and running the app outside QtCreator as a bigger chance of failing because the system will not find Qt DLLs.

Comment: @Gokhan The cellphone example uses canva 3d and qt quick. Maybe you are missing some dependencies like proper OpenGl drivers. Try more basic examples like "Colliding Mice" or "Composition Mode".

Comment: @BenjaminT yeah, it could be a lot of things. Without more info this question is more like an exercise in telepathy. :) Another thing one could think of is that Qt installation is build using different tool-chain, or does not include OpenGL indeed.

Comment: Running in a debugger could possibly also provide important information

Comment: @AMA A wrong toolchain would probably make it fails at compile-time. Also MinGW is distributed with Qt, they should match.

Comment: @BenjaminT I meant more like different MinGW version. I may be wrong, but I think Qt5.7 still uses MinGW 4-something

Comment: @AMA Qt 5.7 uses MinGW 5.3 and looking at the pics, the MinGW should be the one distributed with Qt as it is installed in `C:\Qt\Tools`

Comment: I have just installed on another pc that has the same features with the first installed pc. While I was installing it, chose the recommended setting like before. However although it is running on other pc that was just installed, Qt doesn't run on first installed.

Comment: I just solved this issue, after uninstalled the Visual Studio on my pc. Maybe it helps to someone who get that issue.